# How to continue the multiple event subscription invocation even while there is an exception in one event handler

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

Heres is what i m trying to accomplish . 
I m trying to expose a class with a custom event that i have created. This class will be distributed to the other folks wrapped inside a dll .

Now the requirement is, when the other users are trying to subscribe to this event multiple times, regardless of any exception in any of the subscriber all the other subscribers need to be invoked.

I m aware that using the try and catch blocks within the handlers at the users end, will ensure that the others get invoked , but how do i ensure this at my class level where the event is defined. Is there a flag like ignore exception that i could set at the class level so that all subscribers would be called regardless of any subscriber throwing an exception .

Answer (score 2):

In the class that defines the event you can use the fact it's a multicast delegate and call the members separately, roughly like this:

```
 Delegate[] delegates = myEvent.GetInvocationList();
 foreach (Delegate d in delegates)
 {
     try {
         d.DynamicInvoke(sender, args);
     } catch {
     }
 }
```

Generally it's a good idea to never hide exceptions, at least log them if not showing them to the user

Comment: This, and +1, but I wouldn't just swallow the exceptions even if nobody cares. You should log them, either to a file or the Windows Event Log, just in case anyone begins to care.

Comment: Cant i just do the invoke ? Why would u want to use a dynamic invok?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this and preserve exceptions you can use the following method:

```
    // Extract invocation list and call recursive dispatch:
    RecursiveDispatch(0, myEvent.GetInvocationList(), arguments);

    private static void RecursiveDispatch(int index, Delegate[] delegates, object[] arguments)
    {
        if (delegates == null || index >= delegates.Length)
            return;
        try
        {
            delegates[index].DynamicInvoke(arguments);
        }
        catch
        {
            InternalInvoke(index + 1, delegates, arguments);
            throw;
        }
        InternalInvoke(index + 1, delegates, arguments);
    }
```